# Get URL of current page in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, url

How can I retrieve the complete url of the current webpage, including http? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: How to retrieve a complete url given what?

Comment: It will be nice to know what kind of input you're thinking of. Is the input an IP address, or part of the URL? Otherwise this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: I'm voting for closing since nobody seems to understand the question.

Comment: You were lucky to have someone guess the question correctly. Is it really too much work to give a bit more information about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you mean to get the url of the current page?

Use: `Request.Url.ToString()`

Or if you want to convert a relative Url to the absolute path, I beleive the code is something like this:

```
Request.Url.Host + Page.ResolveUrl(relativeUrl)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the complete URL from the current request context, the [`HttpRequest.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx) property should do the trick. To get a `string` representation within a `Page`:

```
string completeUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
```

Comment: please specify me the namespace for Request.Url..
thanks

Comment: The `HttpRequest` class is in the `System.Web` namespace. In my coe sample, `Request` is a property on `System.Web.Page`. A similar property is available `UserControl` and `HttpContext`.

Comment: sorry.. i am not using usercontrol ... i am using class file here..the thing is i am using dll..

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to resolve, and I doubt that my answer is useful, but what about `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()` ?

Comment: what i am trying to resolve is switching a site between http and https..

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while but:

```
Request.ServerVariables["Url"];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396(VS.90).aspx

or even this reference from 1998!

https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201638/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092298-3.shtml

**EDIT**

From http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
<b>You are browsing this site with:</b>
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("http_user_agent"))%>
</p>
<p>
<b>Your IP address is:</b>
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr"))%>
</p>
<p>
<b>The DNS lookup of the IP address is:</b>
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("remote_host"))%>
</p>
<p>
<b>The method used to call the page:</b>
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("request_method"))%>
</p>
<p>
<b>The server's domain name:</b>
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("server_name"))%>
</p>
<p>
<b>The server's port:</b>
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("server_port"))%>
</p>
<p>
<b>The server's software:</b>
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("server_software"))%>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```